# How to implement canvas design design pattern in css?

Tags: css

Not sure if three column layout is the right term, but here's what I want to do.

I want one "middle" element to fill all available space (if possible without scroll bars).
"Docked" to the left and right, there should be an element each, displaying lists with tools for the middle element.

Bascially, I'm describing the Canvas Design Pattern from Jenifer Tidwell's Designing Interfaces.

Comment: Googling for "3 column layout" turns up countless examples of how to do this

Answer (score 1):

A three column layout is not (necessarily) the same as the canvas pattern:

Here's the html:

```
<div class="canvas-pattern">
    <div class="canvas-pattern-left"></div>
    <div class="canvas-pattern-canvas"></div>
    <div class="canvas-pattern-right"></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
/* canvas-pattern */
/** full screen */
.canvas-pattern-canvas{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -10;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

/*** centered within fullscreen */
.canvas-pattern-canvas > div {
    width: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

/** docking left and right */
.canvas-pattern{
    position: relative;
}

.canvas-pattern-right{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.canvas-pattern-left{
    position: absolute:
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```